# Bootstrap 3 - Vertically Algn Row Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row in Bootstrap. Within this row, I have three columns. The first column has an input field. The second column has some text. The third column has another input field. You can see this layout in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/p8UMBbDBaJ), which includes this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Minimum">Minimum</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Minimum" name="Minimum" type="text" value="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center"><p>Up To</p></div>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Maximum">Maximum</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Maximum" name="Maximum" type="text" value="100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm am trying to figure out how to vertically align the "Up To" text in the middle column. I want to vertically align the text against the bottom of the row. How can I do that?

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: @DanPhilip I just tried the link and it worked for me.

Comment: Its working now. Never mind

Answer (score 0):

The line height for the table rows is 34px, so setting your line height for that element to 68px would vertically align it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on your `row` and set `display: table;`

Then you add another class on your 3 divs and set `display: table-cell;`and `float: inherit;` and a last class on your element you want to align vertically and set `vertical-align: middle;`

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qKOr8xMhCj)